# Styling the UI Fabric Date Picker Callout

Tags: css, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

How could I modify the style of elements inside the callout of the UI Fabric Date Picker? For example highlight the current month?

[image]

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Component-Styling), I should be able to use the DatePicker styles property to target sub-components, but I don't know how to reach specific elements:

```
styles = {
  callout: {
  ... what goes here?
  }
}
```

I am trying to get this to work without having to rely on yet another third party library like styled-components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'callout' object (as the others e.g. icon, root, textField for DatePicker component) expects css-styles (camelCased, no dash).

'Callout' refers to the HTML-element wrapping the popup, Icon tothe Icon in the DatePicker, etc.

```
styles = {
  callout: {
    maxHeight: '300px',
    fontSize: '2rem',
    /* etc */
  },
  icon: {
     color: 'red'
  },
  root: {},
  textField: {}
}
```

**Edit:**

Highlighting the current month you can archive easily via the DatePicker Prop `highlightCurrentMonth` (from doc: 'Whether the month picker should highlight the current month')

[Link to DatePicker doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/datepicker)

Comment: Thank you. What if I wanted to make a change to the month picker that is not available as a prop - for example highlighting it in a different color or make it bold?

Comment: I guess you could overwritte the default styles by using nested CSS-in-JS styling-rules. E.g. Look with the DOM explorer whihc class ms-office adds to the currentActiveMonth, and do something like `styles = {
  callout: {
    '& .ms-current-active-month': { fontWight: 'bold' }
  }
}` I never had to do it, so it's untested, mazbe you need an '!important' to overwrite

Comment: I didn't know about that "&" notation. Where could I learn more about it?

Comment: Is it the library UI Fabric is using for its styles?

Comment: I think MS developed their own but it is heavily based on JSS. Could not find official MS documentation. Please don't quote me on this one, could be wrong ^^

Comment: I just saw in their Github that they migrated from stylesheet to **css-in-js** some time ago.

Comment: Right, they recommend css-in-js but without being very specific about which flavor. I posted an example I came up with, your comment with the & notation put me on the right tracks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Lumpenstein for all the help. I am just posting here an example to showcase the use of the **selectors** and **&** notations:

```
const dpStyles: IDatePickerStyles = {
    root: { /* styles */ },
    textField: { /* styles */ },
    icon: { /* styles */ },
    callout:
      { selectors:
        { '& button': { backgroundColor: "red" }
      }
 }
};
```

Comment: It's annoying to have to use a hack like this to target sub-components like this, but this is definitely the right answer.